# Metal temperature change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, cooling

I have a pipe that’s $70^{\circ}\text{F}$, in a constant room temperature of $80^{\circ}\text{F}$.

I would like an equation to solve for pipe temperature ($\text{F}$) after X amount of time. 
Material: Iron
Height: $100~\mathrm{cm}$
Diameter: $3.81 ~\mathrm{cm}$

Based on this equation, using Newton’s Law of Cooling, I will determine the $k$ (rate of change in temperature/time).

**NOTE**: 
I understand that I’m not accounting for all influences.  Nevertheless, using the provided facts I would like the best solution.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) You might want to ask this question on engineering SE - it could yield more appropriate answers.

Comment: [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) , perhaps are you looking for a simplified and approximative version for this precise question ?

Comment: @igael: in a sense yes, but the general heat equation takes no heat losses into account and would be useless here.

Comment: @gert: I was thinking to Biot number and [lumped system analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model#Thermal_systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest treatment of this kind of problem for an object of mass $m$ and specific heat capacity $c$ is by means of Newton's cooling law, for *convective cooling only*:

$$-\frac{dQ}{dt}=hA(T-T_{\infty})$$

Where $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient, $A$ the total surface area of the object and $T_{\infty}$ the ambient temperature.

Also:

$$dQ=mcdT$$
So:
$$-mc\frac{dT}{dt}=hA(T-T_{\infty})$$
Integrated between $T_1$ and $T_2$, this yields:

$$\Large{T_2=T_{\infty}+(T_1-T_{\infty})e^{-\alpha t}}$$

Where:

$$\alpha = \frac{hA}{mc}$$

$T_1$ is the initial temperature (at $t=0$) and $T_2$ is the temperature at time $t$.

The rate of change in temperature/time is of course not linear and given by:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-\alpha (T_1-T_{\infty})e^{-\alpha t}$$
If needed, the following logarithmic plot allows to determine $\alpha$ experimentally:

$$\ln\Big(\frac{T_2-T_{\infty}}{T_1-T_{\infty}}\Big)=-\alpha t$$

Note that this simple model is based on some assumptions:

1. Heat loss by convection only.
2. Temperature is uniform throughout the object's domain (no temperature gradients due to *conductive* lags).
3. $m, c, h, A$ are temperature invariant.

---

**Edit:**

To answer OP's question in the comments: $T_2$ after $2\:\text{min}=120\:\mathrm{s}$, $T_1=70^{\circ}\text{F}$ and $T_{\infty}=80^{\circ}\text{F}$?

We'll neglect the iron shell and pretend the pipe is all water.

First calculate:
$$\alpha = \frac{hA}{mc}$$

$h \approx 20\:\mathrm{Wm^{-2}K^{-1}}$

$A=\pi D L=0.12\:\mathrm{m^2}$

$m=\rho V=\rho \frac{\pi D^2}{4}L=1.14\:\mathrm{kg}$

$c_{water}=42000\:\mathrm{Jkg^{-1}K^{-1}}$
$$\implies \alpha=0.0005\:\mathrm{s^{-1}}$$

$$T_2=80+(70-80)e^{-0.0005 \times 120}\approx 70.6^{\circ}\text{F}$$

Or more generally:

$$T_2(t)=80-10e^{-0.0005 \times t}$$

**Alternatively** to find the time $t$ to reach a specified temperature $T_2(t)$, use:

$$t=\frac{1}{\alpha} \times \ln\Big(\frac{T_{\infty}-T_1}{T_{\infty}-T_2(t)}\Big)$$

But in that case all temperatures need to be converted to Kelvin first.

For example to take the pipe to $75^{\circ}\text{F}$ in the above conditions would take about $135\:\mathrm{s}$:

$$t=2000\times\ln\frac{299.8-294.3}{299.8-297.0}=1350\:\mathrm{s}=22.5\:\mathrm{min}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Using the formulas above, can you demonstrate what the temperature will be after 2 seconds in a steady and natural air temperature?

Comment: @Cindy: you use the word *"pipe"* give no internal diameter. Is it perchance a *solid rod*?

Comment: Diameter 3.81 cm

Comment: Pipe contains water at 70F.

Comment: @Cindy: using this model I find a temperature increase of a mere $0.01^{\circ}\text{F}$ of the water. The heating time is very small and the temperature difference between the pipe and the ambient air only $10^{\circ}\text{F}$. That explains the small value of temperature rise. Due to uncertainty on $h$ and other model limitations this is really an *order of magnitude* rather than a precise value.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that h at 80 F is 0.0299 (natural air environment)?  Additionally, showing the values used (h,c,m,dT,etc), can you plug in 2 minutes for t and demonstrate how you solve for temperature? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Gert.  I really appreciate your assistance and clarity.  I have a couple of questions which I added as an Edit above.  Thanks.

Comment: Which edit are you referring to?

Comment: Surface area: you're correct, due to a typo I got 0.012 $m^2$, that should have been 0.12$m^2$. Mea culpa. I'll adjust the calculated values. As regards your numbers, I don't really know what they stand for. Using the formulas given (**and using Kelvin when advised**) it should be simple to verify them.

Comment: As 'luck' would have it the error was on $L$ which affects both $A$ **and** $m$, so $\alpha$ was unaffected and the calculated values remained unchanged.

Comment: Based on empirical data, $T_2$ = 336.47K, $T_1$ = 300.42K, and $T∞$ = 301.15, $t$ = 300 sec.  Goal is to solve for $k$.  I have come across 2 different equations.  First equation: $T_2$ = $T_1$ + ($T∞$ - $T_1$) $e$ ^ -kt.  However, the equation that you provided above is: $T_2$ = $T∞$ + ($T_1$ - $T∞$) $e$ ^ -kt.  Can you please clarify when each one is used.

Comment: It is ALWAYS $T_2=T_{\infty}+(T_1-T_{\infty})e^{-kt}$. The object always strives to take on the temperature of the environment (a law of Thermodynamics). Given $t=\infty$ then $T_2=T_{\infty}$.

Comment: Do you have a link to determine $h≈20Wm−2K−1$ based on varying Kelvin temperatures?

Comment: $h$ is considered constant in reasonable temperature intervals (as here). The value used is of course the "Achilles' heel" of the whole calculation, as it is hard to find specific and accurate values for it. Usually it is determined empirically from $k,\alpha$. That would require at least 10 data-points though. The 20 estimate you'll find on several heat engineering web pages. Search for *heat transfer coefficient table*.

Comment: Thanks. Given empirical data of $T_1$ = 294.14, $T_2$ = 294.43, $T_∞$ = 300.43, $t$ = 300 sec.  Solving for $k$, $k$ = .0002.  However, being that there is barely a change in temperature, I would've expected a larger difference between this calculated $k$ and $a$ demonstrated above where $hA/mc=.0005$.

Comment: **Only** a statistical analysis of a significant number of data points can make meaningful statements about that. Have you thought about *upvoting* my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44636/discussion-between-cindy-and-gert).

Comment: Absolutely! You have been a great help! (Better than I ever anticipated :) ) And you've been extremely responsive.  Being that this is my first time posting on stack exchange, I wasn't familiar with the rating system but I immediately marked this answer as correct and anyone reading this should know that.

Comment: Although I don't understand why a significant number of data points is necessary, I uploaded 10 samples to chats.

Comment: Where's chat? Statistical analysis is needed because of measuring error on data points. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Oh, I see them. Gimme some time.

Comment: Please see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277061/rate-of-water-temperature-change
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In my thinking that you may use following equation

$\frac{dT}{dt}\propto-(T-T_0)$

$\frac{1}{T-T_0}dT=-kdt$

$T-T_0=Ce^{-kt}$

from graphical method you may estimate the value of k.